# How to determine gradient of vector in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

I am wondering how to actually determine the gradient of a vector in cylindrical coordinates. I have seen a lot of websites that just say what the general form is but I cannot seem to understand how they got there.

The vector in cylindrical coordinates that I am going to use so everyone can follow along is going to be $\vec{V}=V_{r}\hat{r}+V_{\theta}\hat{\theta}+V_{z}\hat{z}$

Comment: Did you mean  "the gradient of an scalar function" ?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Sorry. The function I would be dealing with is still the one above

Comment: As far as I have seen, gradient of a scalar function is well-known not a vector. for a vector we can speak about its "div" or "curl".

Comment: I am working on a problem where I am trying to find the divergence of the vector in cylindrical coordinates but I need to find its gradient in order to do that. I have found the general form of the gradient online but I would like to understand how that was produced instead of copying it

Comment: Are you familiar to curvilinear coordinates for a point in $\mathbb R ^3$?

Comment: @BabakS. The gradient of a scalar field IS a vector, your second post is incorrect since we actually can speak about the div and curl of the gradient vector field

Comment: @IvanLerner: I mean $A=A_1e_1+A_2e_2+A_3e_3$ for example. :)

Comment: The gradient of a vector is defined in tensor calculus : $\nabla x_i e_i = e_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} x_i e_i = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Look, e.g., at [this](http://www.academia.edu/3003410/Gradient_Divergence_and_Curl_in_Curvilinear_Coordinates) explanation of how a gradient of a (scalar) function is defined in curvilinear coordinates.

Comment: @DoctorDan: I don't know much about the tensor calculus. In fact, I thought that he 's asking about a very common problem in multivariable calculus. Indeed, if he knows the curvilinear coordinates, then we can easily kill the problem. ;-)

Comment: @Babak S, Correct. The OP should look it up in any Vector Calculus textbook or online (my second comment; just edited it for clarity).

Comment: @DoctorDan that resource is very helpful. I took multivariable calculus about 4 years ago and we are having a review in my graduate level fluid mechanics course and I am trying to remember all this stuff. Am I right in saying that the gradient of $\hat{V}$ in my original post is a vector and the divergence would be a scalar?

Comment: If $\hat{V}$ is a scalar, then yes, its gradient is a vector. The divergence of a vector is a scalar. The gradient of a vector is not usually defined in the context of Vector Calculus.

Answer (score 5):

On any Riemannian manifold (not necessarily curved), the *gradient* of a function is the metric dual of the exterior derivative.

The exterior derivative relative to *any* coordinate system of a function is just

$$ \mathrm{d}f = \partial_{x^1} f \mathrm{d}x^1 + \partial_{x^2} f \mathrm{d}x^2 + \cdots + \partial_{x^k} f \mathrm{d}x^k $$

What we need to do, then, is to "hit it with the inverse metric".

In cylindrical coordinates, the metric is

$$ \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2 \mathrm{d}\theta^2 + \mathrm{d}z^2 $$

which we can write as the matrix $\mathrm{diag}(1, r^2, 1)$. Inverting the matrix gives $\mathrm{diag}(1, r^{-2}, 1)$ and so the inverse metric is

$$ \hat{r}^2 + r^{-2} \hat{\theta}^2 + \hat{z}^2 $$

So applying the inverse metric to the differential form $\mathrm{d}f$ we get

$$ \nabla f = \partial_r f \hat{r} + r^{-2} \partial_\theta f \hat{\theta} + \partial_z f \hat{z} $$

the coefficients I note are computed by taking the inverse metric as a matrix, and multiplying to it the exterior derivative as a column vector:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ & r^{-2} \\ & & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \partial_r f \\ \partial_\theta f \\ \partial_z f \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $1/r$ instead of $1/r^2$?

Comment: Depends on what you use as the basis. I am using the coordinate basis $\{\partial_r, \partial_\theta, \partial_z\}$ (in the above denoted by $\hat{r}, \hat{\theta}, \hat{z}$) to decompose tangent vectors. Alternatively you can use a normalized basis consisting of $\{\partial_r, r^{-1} \partial_\theta, \partial_z\}$ in which case multiplication by $1/r$ would be correct.

Answer (score 3):

I've derived it in the easiest way. Note each term in the gradient tensor is described in tensor notation:
$$\nabla \vec v_{ij}=\nabla_j\vec v \cdot e_i$$
Where $\nabla_j$ means jth component of del operator. Apply this to each term in gradient tensor as below.

$\nabla\vec v_{rr}=\nabla_r\vec v\cdot\hat r=\frac{\partial\vec v}{\partial r}\cdot\hat r=\left(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}\hat r+\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial r}\hat\theta+\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}\hat z\right)\cdot\hat r=\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}$
$\nabla\vec v_{r\theta}=\nabla_{\theta }\vec v\cdot \hat r=\frac{\partial \vec v}{r\partial \theta }\cdot \hat{r}=\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial {v}_r}{\partial \theta }\hat{r}+{v}_r\hat{\theta }+\frac{\partial {v}_{\theta }}{\partial \theta }\hat{\theta }-{v}_{\theta }\hat{r}+\frac{\partial {v}_z}{\partial \theta }\hat{z}\right)\cdot \hat{r}=\frac{\partial {v}_r}{r\partial \theta }-\frac{{v}_{\theta }}{r}$
$\nabla\vec v_{rz}=\nabla_z\vec v\cdot\hat r=\frac{\partial\vec v}{\partial z}\cdot\hat r=\left(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z}\hat r+\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial z}\hat\theta+\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z\hat z}\right)\cdot\hat r=\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z}$
$\nabla\vec v_{\theta r}=\nabla_r\vec v\cdot\hat\theta=\frac{\partial\vec v}{\partial r}\cdot\hat\theta=\left(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}\hat r+\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial r}\hat\theta+\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}\hat z\right)\cdot\hat\theta=\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial r}$
$\nabla\vec v_{\theta\theta}=\nabla_\theta\vec v\cdot\hat\theta=\frac{\partial \vec v}{r\partial\theta}\cdot\hat\theta=\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial\theta}\hat r+v_r\hat\theta+\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial\theta}\hat\theta-v_\theta\hat r+\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial\theta}\hat z\right)\cdot\hat\theta=\frac{\partial v_\theta}{r\partial\theta}+\frac{v_r}{r}$
$\nabla\vec v_{\theta z}=\nabla_{z}\vec v\cdot\hat\theta=\frac{\partial\vec v}{\partial z}\cdot\hat\theta=\left(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z}\hat r+\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial z}\hat\theta+\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}\hat z\right)\cdot\hat\theta=\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial z}$
$\nabla\vec v_{zr}=\nabla_r\vec v\cdot\hat z=\frac{\partial\vec v}{\partial r}\cdot\hat z=\left(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}\hat r+\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial r}\hat\theta+\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}\hat z\right)\cdot\hat z=\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}$
$\nabla\vec v_{z\theta}=\nabla_\theta\vec v\cdot\hat z=\frac{\partial\vec v}{r\partial\theta}\cdot\hat z=\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial\theta }\hat r+v_r\hat\theta+\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial\theta}\hat\theta-v_\theta\hat r+\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial\theta}\hat z\right)\cdot \hat z=\frac{\partial v_z}{r\partial\theta}$
$\nabla\vec v_{zz}=\nabla_z\vec v\cdot\hat z=\frac{\partial\vec v}{\partial z}\cdot\hat z=\left(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z}\hat r+\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial z}\hat\theta+\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}\hat z\right)\cdot\hat z=\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}$

Finally, we've obtained the full terms of tensor.
$$\nabla\vec v=\begin{bmatrix}\nabla\vec v_{rr}&\nabla\vec v_{r\theta}&\nabla\vec v_{rz}\\\nabla\vec v_{\theta r}&\nabla\vec v_{\theta \theta}&\nabla\vec v_{\theta z}\\\nabla\vec v_{zr}&\nabla\vec v_{z\theta}&\nabla\vec v_{zz}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial v_r}{r\partial\theta}-\frac{v_\theta}{r}&\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z}\\\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial v_\theta}{r\partial\theta}+\frac{v_r}{r}&\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial z}\\\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial v_z}{r\partial\theta}&\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}$$
Refer to my site for more information :
https://blog.naver.com/richscskia/221744783715

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1294585)

Comment: I've added the essential parts of it to address your comment and leave the link just for reference. Thank you for advice.